# How to get notified of Google App Engine Task Queue failure

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using a [GAE push Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/). I want the task to run once and if it fails I want it to notify me somehow. I also don't want it to do any retries. If it fails I want it to sit in the queue until I rerun it manually.

I can manually catch all exceptions and send an email to myself it it fails. Is there a better way?
In the queue config I can specify retry limit (see below) of zero but if I do this the task is deleted as soon as it fails.

```
# queue.yaml
- name: default
  rate: 5/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of to accomplish this would be to set a high value for min_backoff_seconds.  If you can set that for something high like 7 days, then that should give you enough time to take action in response to your email message.

I don't know if there is a limit to how high a value you can set for min_backoff_seconds so you'll want to check that.

I think catching exceptions and sending yourself an email is the only way to notify yourself of a task failure.

Answer (score 5):

When a task retries, you can read the retry count in next retry. And do what you need to do.

Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) for : X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount, the number of times this task has been retried; for the first attempt, this value is 0. This number includes attempts where the task failed due to a lack of available instances and never reached the execution phase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think of any way to do what you want besides grabbing all exceptions. GAE won't send a message when a taskqueue fails, there is no service to "allow" to get that functionality unfortunately.

Unless you get a Google Engineer to answer something about a service I'm not aware of....

Answer (score 0):

@voscausa's answer means that: you can implement a `taskCheckerTask` that always returns http codes any number except between 200-299. But **do not forget task will be deleted from queue** if it fails.

```
class TaskChecker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # Check tasks and retries here
        # If need send mail
        self.echo(500)
```